# Does Any one know how to create Nokia virtual Devise (Emulator) For Test and Debug Android Application?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, nokia

Currently I am facing that my Android Application getting Crash Nokia 5 (Android 8.1) device but it working fine in other devices. I don't have Actual Nokia 5 Device there for I am trying to create Nokia Emulator.